# Como enviar uma string para a minha Api .net atravez do axios

Tags: api, vue.js, asp.net-web-api, axios, back-end

Estou tentando enviar uma string para a minha API (DotNet 6) utilizando no front o Vue.js + vuetify e adicionei o axios para poder fazer as requisições.

Porem ao enviar o meu parametro como string está retornando o erro 400.

Esse é o metodo que chama  a minha API:

```
recEmail(){
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/recpw", this.emailSentForRecovery)
      .then((res) => (console.log(res)))
}
```

Essa é a minha API:

```
[HttpPost("/recpw")]
    public async Task<bool> recPassword([FromBody] string email) 
    {
        var authEmail = await _userServices.GetUser(email);

        if (authEmail != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

E estou tendo esse retorno:
[Erro:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifyjv.png)

Answer (score -2):

Até onde eu entendi a propriedade emailSentForRecovery nao é uma string
Tente: `{email: 'stringexemplo'}`

Ou se emailSentForRecovery for uma string Tente: `{email: emailSentForRecovery }`

Como fica:

```
recEmail(){
  axios
    .post("http://localhost:8080/recpw", {email: emailSentForRecovery })
      .then((res) => (console.log(res)))
}
```